# How to make my code read more than one digit at a time? One digit input works but two-digit or more inputs does not work

Tags: python, for-loop, max, computer-science, min

I am a beginner in Python. My code works for one-digit numbers but not two-digit. I know the for-loop is reading user input one digit at a time but I have no idea how to make it read my input like it would in an array. Ex. 5,7,9 is read as 5,7,9 but 5,70, 9 is read 5, 7, 9.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    try:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        num1 = float(num)

    except:
        if "done" == num:
            break
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

    for value in num:
        if smallest is None:
            smallest = num
        if num < smallest:
            smallest = num
            #print(smallest, num)
        elif largest is None:
            largest = num
        if num > largest:
            largest = num
            #print("Maximumcc is:", largest)

print("Maximum is:", largest)
print("Minimum is: ", smallest)
```

Comment: Why are you using a loop `for value in num`? Just test `num1`.

Comment: `nums = [flaot(n) for n in num.split(",")]`

Comment: `num` is a string and as a string it will compare poorly against other strings in the event that they both are strings of digits.  "12" **is less than** "9" in the world or strings :-).  You seem to have started to account for that with `num1` but you left off using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looping over the wrong thing.

You need to split the input at comma characters. Then loop over those elements, converting each of them to `float` and testing it.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    response = input("Enter numbers separated by comma, or 'done': ")
    if response == 'done':
        break

    try:
        nums = [float(num) for num in response.split(',')]
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

    for num in nums:
        if smallest is None or num < smallest:
            smallest = num
        if largest is None or num > largest:
            largest = num

print("Maximum is:", largest)
print("Minimum is: ", smallest)
```